# How do I access a USB serial port without an entry in /dev?

Tags: debian, usb, serial-port

I have a USB to serial adapter based on the SiLabs CP2101 chipset. I'm trying to use it with Debian 5.0 Lenny (armel architecture).

I seem to be able to get the proper kernel module to recognize the adapter, but it won't create `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

I ran `modprobe usbserial` and `modprobe cp2101` and then connected the device, resulting in the following output from `dmesg`:

```
usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using mv5182_ehci and address 8
usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
cp2101 2-1:1.0: cp2101 converter detected
usb 2-1: reset full speed USB device using mv5182_ehci and address 8
usb 2-1: cp2101 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

However, `/dev/ttyUSB0` does not exist. There are no new files in `/dev`.

`find / -type f -name ttyUSB0` gives no results.

I did find a bunch of *directories* named `ttyUSB0` that showed up after plugging in the device:

```
/sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0
/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp2101/ttyUSB0
/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0
/sys/devices/platform/mv5182_ehci.1/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/ttyUSB0
 ...
```

I found a file at `/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/ttyUSB0/dev` but it does not appear to be a serial port; I can't open it with `screen` or Python's serial module.

To compare, I tried my Debian 6.0 development machine (which has a newer version of the cp2101 module now called `cp210x`) and after seeing the "converter now attached to ttyUSB0" line in `dmesg`, `/dev/ttyUSB0` appears.

How do I get the `cp2101` module to create `/dev/ttyUSB0`? If I can't, what file do I open to access the serial port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try making the device node manually. On my system `/dev/ttyUSB0` is `major 188` and `minor 0`. And hopefully, my supposition is correct that it's a type `c` meaning character device (maybe try `u` for unbuffered character device if `c` doesn't work).

```
mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 188 0
```

If this worked, and the device file was appearing automatically before, something in your `udev` is messed up. There could also be an issue with USB subsystem settings or drivers.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I still need to figure out how to get it do this automatically, but at least I can continue with testing.

Comment: BTW, this is a fresh Debian 5.0 image on an embedded system. It could just be that the kernel modules (or settings) that came with Debian 5.0 don't work right. Where can I look for settings that might be relevant?