# GSM modem does not create /dev/ttyUSB file

Tags: linux, usb, devices, serial-console, modem

I installed [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org) in a server, and I want to use a GSM 3G USB modem to
send/receive SMS messages, as described in section *SMS Centers > GSM
Modem* of the Kannel User Guide.

I have already installed, configured and tested Kannel on my notebook
successfully.

When I plug the modem into my notebook, a device named `/dev/ttyUSB0`
appears. It acts as a serial port to send commands to the modem.

I have to put this device in the Kannel configuration file.

After some testing, I decided to install Kannel in the production server. The server runs **Linux-VServer**, and my task is to install Kannel on the
*host* and PlaySMS in one of the *guests*, which runs Apache.

The problem is that I can't find any device analogous to the `ttyUSB0` that is created in my machine (and AFAIK, in all normal Linux boxes).

Here are some diagnostic commands. The modems used are not the same model, but I have already tested Sierra 308 on my notebook and it works, too.

#### My notebook - Arch Linux

`uname -a`:

```
Linux twoflower 3.4.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 15 18:11:01 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg` when I plug the modem in (Huawei 156B):

```
[35328.849886] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
[35329.007281] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-2:1.2
[35329.010054] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-2:1.3
[35329.301153] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[35329.302155] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[35329.303064] USB Serial support registered for generic
[35329.303221] usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
[35329.368043] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[35329.368960] USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[35329.369332] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[35329.377484] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[35329.377567] option 1-2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[35329.378930] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[35330.013635] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31
PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[35330.019275] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   MMC Storage      2.31
PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[35330.028997] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[35330.214473] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[35330.214484] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[35330.216603] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

#### Server - Debian Lenny

`uname -a`:

```
Linux macunaima 2.6.26-1-vserver-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 13 20:19:13 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg` when I plug the modem in (Sierra 308):

```
  [    3.246112] usb 8-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
  [    3.381966] usb 8-4: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 9 but
  max is 5
  [    3.382076] usb 8-4: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 7 but
  max is 5
  [    3.382184] usb 8-4: config 1 has no interface number 2
  [    3.382285] usb 8-4: config 1 has no interface number 5
  [    3.384576] usb 8-4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
  [    3.389070] usb 8-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0f3d,
  idProduct=68a3
  [    3.389070] usb 8-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2,
  SerialNumber=4
  [    3.389070] usb 8-4: Product: USB 308
  [    3.389070] usb 8-4: Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
  [    3.389070] usb 8-4: SerialNumber: 353354045586405
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0f3d:68a3 Airprime, Incorporated
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

#### Previous questions

The only previous question with a similar problem that I found here was [How do I access a USB serial port without an entry in /dev?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42844/how-do-i-access-a-usb-serial-port-without-an-entry-in-dev).

In his case, `dmesg` said that `ttyUSB0` was created, which does not occur in my case.

Anyway, I have tried the solution posted there, using `mknod` to create devices manually:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
    sudo mknod /dev/ttyUSB$i c 188 $i
done
```

I created all these devices because `lsusb` says that the device is plugged in  `Bus 008 Device 002`.

It did not work. I tested it with `picocom`, and this it says (to all these devices, not only `ttyUSB0`):

```
$ picocom -
FATAL: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such device or address
```

While in my notebook, `picocom` works fine:

```
$ picocom -b 9600 /dev/ttyUSB0
Terminal ready
AT                      # my input
OK
```

Comment: This error looks strange, can you try a newer kernel in your server?

Answer (score 3):

I'm with @Renan: it looks like this problem was fixed in newer kernels. ([One such thread on LKML.](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg64164.html))

The key error is the `invalid interface number` one. It means the USB driver sees the device, but it's numbering its features (interfaces) in a way the driver doesn't expect, and it can't cope. Googling around, you can find several cases where people are fixing weaknesses in the kernel to cope with these newer devices, and their odd interface numbering behavior.

I'm not 100% certain on this, since I can't find a definitive document that says either that out-of-order interface numbers are wrong, or that it's all been fixed for all USB devices in kernel x.y.z. It appears to be more of a [Whac-a-Mole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole) sort of development effort.

Upgrading the kernel on a server is not an easy fix by any means. I would try an intermediate step to check the hypothesis first: put your server's version of Debian in to a VM, make a snapshot, upgrade the kernel there, and see if it will see the USB device after the upgrade. (Obviously you need to be using VM software that will push a USB device into the VM. Most will these days.)

If that doesn't work, you can easily roll back to the snapshot, since this VM should be useful for future testing before you roll something out to the prodouction server.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem as you. Try to install the `gsm-utils` package.

```
apt-get install gsm-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given I think the system doesn't have the configuration file of that USB device. Get the correct `conf`, add it in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d` and activate it. Then it will be detected as USB device.

Refer to [this article](http://importgeek.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/how-to-connect-reliance-netconnect-huawei-ec156-in-ubuntu/).